# How to install GMP extension for PHP

Tags: php, gmp

I was getting the following error when trying to run `composer update` on a SimpleSAML project.

```
- openid/php-openid dev-master requires ext-gmp * -> the requested PHP extension gmp is missing from your system.
```

Running `sudo apt-get install php5-gmp` did not work and neither did `sudo apt-get install php7-gmp`

Comment: What does "did not work" mean? Did apt-get report an error (php7-gmp doesn't exist) or did it install fine but not help (php5-gmp is not used by php7)? The command `apt search php gmp` gives you the list of relevant packages, it suggests that you should install php-gmp if you are using whatever the current default version of PHP is, or php7.0-gmp if you very specifically want to use PHP version 7.0.

Comment: Yes. The error was that the package did not exist. Oh `apt search php gmp` would have been a great thing to do.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

To install GMP for PHP7.0 on Ubuntu, run:
`sudo apt-get install php7.0-gmp`

Make sure your `php.ini` contains the following:
`extension=php_gmp.so`

To find out where your `php.ini` is located, run:
`php --ini`

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed it !

Comment: after running the command and adding lines in php.ini file, its i don't get gmp module installed.

Comment: there's no need to add that line to ini file. it's included automatically.

Comment: @Ganesh K you need to install the same version of GMP as your PHP. If you have multiple PHP installs on your machine, you can install GMP for each of them.

Comment: I had to restart apache2 too, adding the line to ini file was not needed.

Answer (score 21):

For PHP 7.2:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-gmp
```

Answer (score 18):

The new way in PHP 7 to install extensions is to just write "php-EXTENSION"
In this case it's as simple as:

```
sudo apt-get install php-gmp
```

Comment: Importantly this works for PHP 8 as well!

Answer (score 13):

***For PHP 7.4:***

```sh
sudo apt-get install php7.4-gmp
```

***SO:*** *Ubuntu 20.04*

Answer (score 13):

For docker based on official php images like `php:7.2-fpm`

Just add this to Dockerfile

```
RUN apt install -y libgmp-dev && docker-php-ext-install gmp
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are running php 7.2 and above, then

`sudo apt-get install php7.2-gmp`

or you can as well install `bcmath` extension using

`sudo apt-get install php7.2-bcmath`

I recommend you install both of them, after complete install restart apache

`sudo service apache2 reload`

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 6):

Thank you it helps me. I use PHP 7.2. 
Therefore, I run:

1. `sudo apt-get install php7.2-gmp`
2. `extension=php_gmp.so`

Answer (score 5):

```
apt-get install php7.1-gmp
```

That's it.

Comment: on ubuntu 16.04lts its says, unable to locate packege php7.1-gmp

Answer (score 4):

for centos

```
sudo yum install php-gmp
```

for ubuntu

```
sudo apt install php-gmp
```

also enable php extension in ini file

```
extension=php_gmp.so
```

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: apt-get has evolved over the years into just apt.  On modern systems this will detect the php version, etc.

`sudo apt install php-gmp`

Comment: not on my Ubuntu 18
I had to run  "sudo apt-get install php7.3-gmp" to finally get it working

Answer (score 1):

It's better to search using `package` or `dependency manager` installed in machine. 
For `yum`, you can search using `yum search gmp` and then install.

```
yum search gmp
```

This will yield these search results

```
Loaded pluginss: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
170 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
========================================================= N/S matched: gmp ==========================================================
perl-Math-BigInt-GMP.x86_64 : Math::BigInt::GMP Perl module
python-gmpy2.x86_64 : Python 2 interface to GMP, MPFR, and MPC
gmp.x86_64 : A GNU arbitrary precision library
gmp.i686 : A GNU arbitrary precision library
gmp-devel.x86_64 : Development tools for the GNU MP arbitrary precision library
gmp-static.x86_64 : Development tools for the GNU MP arbitrary precision library
mingw32-gmp.noarch : Cross-compiled GNU arbitrary precision library
mingw64-gmp.noarch : Cross-compiled GNU arbitrary precision library
perl-Math-GMP.x86_64 : High speed arbitrary size integer math
php-gmp.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the GNU MP library
```

Now install extension with:
`yum install php-gmp.x86_64`

Answer (score -2):

For PHP 7.3 try this.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3 -gmp
extension=php_gmp.so
```

in Ubuntu