# How can I install PHP extensions to satisfy composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, gmp

I am creating a app and am trying to install a library into my project though composer.

Composer has given me the error:

> Problem 1
>       - The requested PHP extension ext-gmp * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gmp extension.

Ok, it seems like I need to gmp extension.

I am using a Mac, and using a local test server with XAMPP.

Now this is where it starts getting confusing. I went to my XAMPP php.ini and remove the ";" from gmp extension like this:
[xampp attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0l90.png)

I retried composer installation with no luck. My next thought was that the extension needs to be installed on the global PHP Mac installation... I removed the ";" for gmp on that php.ini, but no luck. How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you reboot XAMPP? Does the extension show up in the output of `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Have you installed the extension yet? Just uncommenting the line in php.ini does not enable an extension if it is not installed...

Comment: @NicoHaase I have ran brew install gmp with no luck.

Comment: What do you mean by "no luck"? And does `brew install homebrew/php/php70-gmp` work?

Comment: Check it. It maybe help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40010197/how-to-install-gmp-on-php7-and-ubuntu/40010211

Answer (score -2):

-if you need it for php 5 use

```
   brew install homebrew/php/php55-gmp
```

-if you need it for php 7 use

```
   brew install homebrew/php/php70-gmp
```

-and if you don't have homebrew, you can install it using this command

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

OR you can jsut run

```
   brew install php@7.1
```

since it have all the packages you need for php 7.1