# Laravel Socialite Install Eror

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

I am trying to install laravel socialite plugin using this command

```
composer require laravel/socialite
```

but i got this

> Using version ^3.0 for laravel/socialite ./composer.json has been
>   updated Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could
>   not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - fgrosse/phpasn1 2.0.1 requires ext-gmp * -> the requested PHP extension gmp is missing from your system.
>       - fgrosse/phpasn1 2.0.1 requires ext-gmp * -> the requested PHP extension gmp is missing from your system.
>       - fgrosse/phpasn1 2.0.1 requires ext-gmp * -> the requested PHP extension gmp is missing from your system.
>       - Installation request for fgrosse/phpasn1 (locked at 2.0.1) -> satisfiable by fgrosse/phpasn1[2.0.1].
>
> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini
>   files:
>       - C:\xampp\php\php.ini   You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
>
> content.

Comment: this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40010197/how-to-install-gmp-on-php7-and-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows simply download the php_gmp..dll place it in your php extension folder and then add this line in your php.ini

```
extension=php_gmp.so
```

Dont forget to restart you webserver (apache).

if you are on linux

simply run

```
sudo apt-get install php*-gmp
```

then restart your server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Hope this helps