# Unable to Purchase. Contact the developer for more information Subscription offer

Tags: objective-c, openssl, storekit

I am adding a subscription offer to my existing in-app purchase. So I get the encoded signature, nonce, timestamp and key identifier from our server. I create a SKPaymentDiscount object and setting this to paymentDiscount of SKMutablePayment object.

It showed me the expected offer price and actual price screen with password field. After I confirmed the subscription with password it takes me to the popup "Unable to purchase contact the development for more information." with an Ok button. Next after I tap the button it shows another alert Failed Cannot connect to iTunes Store.

I got the signature from following this tutorial using python. [Generating a Signature for Subscription Offers - Xcode - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55414749/generating-a-signature-for-subscription-offers-xcode-swift)

```
- (void)buyProduct:(SKProduct*)product offer:(SKPaymentDiscount*)promotionalOffer
{
    SKMutablePayment* payment = [ SKMutablePayment paymentWithProduct:product ];
    payment.paymentDiscount = promotionalOffer;

    [ [ SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue ] addPayment:payment ];
}
```

I want the subscription to be purchased successfully.

Comment: Did you find something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same thing right now.
So I'm not sure either, but your code snippet is missing the code below.

```
payment.applicationUsername = self.appUsernameHash
```

Apple is talking about ʻapplicationUsername` in [Official Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/implementing_subscription_offers_in_your_app).