# When Install composer in laravel get error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, php-ini

Here is the error when running composer install.
Laravel Version is 5.7

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for mdanter/ecc v0.5.2 -> satisfiable by mdanter/ecc[v0.5.2].
    - mdanter/ecc v0.5.2 requires ext-gmp * -> the requested PHP extension gmp is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - mdanter/ecc v0.5.2 requires ext-gmp * -> the requested PHP extension gmp is missing from your system.
    - spomky-labs/jose v7.1.0 requires mdanter/ecc 0.5.* -> satisfiable by mdanter/ecc[v0.5.2].
    - Installation request for spomky-labs/jose v7.1.0 -> satisfiable by spomky-labs/jose[v7.1.0].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Comment: Seems like you need to install GMP have you tried installing it? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40010211/11801683

Comment: @jewishmoses i using windows so please help how to install GMP in windows system