# GMP PHP Extention Missing

Tags: php, xampp, localhost, gmp, php-gmp

I want to test run a completely developed site. While i was in location "localhost/install/" called "Easy Installer by Viserlab" there is showing GMP PHP Extension is Required. How I can install it and where to.

Answer (score -1):

There is already a topic about this at [How to install GMP extension for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40010197/how-to-install-gmp-for-php7-on-ubuntu)

> To install GMP for PHP7.0 on Ubuntu, run: `sudo apt-get install php7.0-gmp`
>
> Make sure your php.ini contains the following: `extension=php_gmp.so`
>
> To find out where your php.ini is located, run: `php --ini`
>
> Or using
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install php-gmp
> ```